# Project in Eclipse not finding javax.servlet.* with open liberty

Tags: eclipse, open-liberty, myeclipse

I'm trying to run a java project with open liberty, but the servlet API is not being found.

[image: code]

- I'm using the WebSphere Application Server Liberty Profile v8.5
  server and its pointing to a valid open liberty instance.
  2.  In the project facets Dynamic Web Module is selected &  WebSphere Application Server Liberty Profile is checked.

What is missing?

**Update**

Here is some extra info.

```
Java 1.8
OL 21.0.0.11
myeclipse 2020.9.16
Facets: Dynamic Web Module 3.0
Open Liberty Features
<featureManager>
    <feature>javaee-8.0</feature>
    <feature>restConnector-2.0</feature>
    <feature>monitor-1.0</feature>
    <feature>localConnector-1.0</feature>
</featureManager>
```

Comment: What *versions* are those selected facets set to? Is `javax.servlet` the package for those versions?

Comment: If you have a `module-info.java` file, delete it (if needed you can recreate it later via right-click on project and _Configure_) or [in `module-info.java` add the required `requires ...;` statement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Platform_Module_System#Properties_of_modules).

Comment: See above for facet info.  fyi, this is java 8.